# Include not work with subtypes - EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I hava a class "Employee" on which I have added the following fields:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[MaxLength(50)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

I have two others classes "Senior" and "Junior" on which I have added the following fields:

```
[Key]
[ForeignKey("Employee")]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public Employee Employee { get; set; }
```

"Junior" and "Senior" each have specific fields (in addition to the common fields found in Employee).

In summary, the "Senior" and "Junior" classes share the same key as the "Employee" class. 
In SQL, the Id field (in "Senior" and "Junior" tables) is a Primary Key and a Foreign Key.

This system works perfectly !

**My problem is this: I would like to be able to access Junior from an instance of Employee (for example : employees[0].Junior)**

To do this, I added the following fields in the Employee class:

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public Senior Senior { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Id")]
public Junior Junior { get; set; }
```

With Entity Framework, I get all Employee like this:

```
var employees = _context.Employees.Include("Junior").Include("Senior").ToList();
```

**The problem is that all Junior and Senior fields are null. The "Include" instruction does not seem to work.**

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `ForeignKey` attributes, but you probably should have collections on the other entity - `Senior` and `Junior` should have a collection of `Employee`. EF figures it out automatically, if you let it generate the database for you.